# Unable to export c3.js charts with DIV elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I have created this chart using c3.js

[image]

Top's two text/number rows are in Div. Bottom Left's two buttons are converting this SVG chart into png and pdf successfully. Now my client wants top's two text rows to be export with PDF and JPG. But PDF and JPG programs only exporting SVG elements. How can I add those two text rows with SVG with the same formatting so that they can export with chart ?

I tried adding div into SVG element using this javascript code.

```
var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var svg = document.querySelector( 'svg' );
var foreignObject = document.createElementNS( ns, 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.setAttribute('height', 300);
foreignObject.setAttribute('width', '100%');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div><div class="export-text"><span class="export-text-heading">{{DISPLAY DATA HERE}}</span></div></div>';
foreignObject.appendChild( div ); 
svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
```

There is multiple `div` inside output. But JPG and PDF exporter programs are not allowing to export div and showing this error.

> There was an error loading the data URI as an image on the following
>   SVG

My PDF Export code is

```
function export_pdf_tracker(){
  $('#chart-tracker').find('svg').attr('xmlns','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
  xepOnline.Formatter.Format('chart-tracker',{pageWidth:'20in', pageHeight:'15.5in',render:'download', srctype:'svg', filename:'Activity-Tracker-Report', resolution:'300', cssStyle:[{fontSize:'40px'},{fontWeight:'bold'}]});
}
```

and my PNG/JPG export code is

```
function svgToPng(chartID) {
    //fix weird back fill
    d3.select('#'+chartID).selectAll("path").attr("fill", "none");
    //fix no axes
    d3.select('#'+chartID).selectAll("path.domain").attr("stroke", "black");
    //fix no tick
    d3.select('#'+chartID).selectAll(".tick line").attr("stroke", "black");
    var svgElement = $('#'+chartID).find('svg')[0];
    saveSvgAsPng(svgElement, chartID+'.png');
}
```

both codes are successfully working but not with `div` element.

This is how it display when I add div over graph.

[image]

but unable to export with `div`. Please suggest if there any way to add this two row's layout in SVG graph so that it can export easily or is there any code to convert div into svg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I have written this code to add each text block. So I create 8 text blocks. Now they are perfectly exporting in JPG and PDF.

```
d3.select("#chart-tracker svg").append("text")
 .attr("x", 780 )
 .attr("y", 50)
 .style("text-anchor", "left")
 .style("font-size", "17px")
 .text("Start Date");
```